# Django REST Framework: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I know that there are answers regarding Django Rest Framework, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have the following setup in Django REST Framework:

**models.py:**

```
class Variant(models.Model):
    variant = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    multiple = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    variants = models.ForeignKey(Variant, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class VariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Variant
        fields = ['id', 'variant']


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    variants = VariantSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id', 'question', 'multiple', 'variants', 'answer']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        variants_data = validated_data.pop('variants')
        question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for variant in variants_data:
            Variant.objects.create(question=question, **variant)

        return question


class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'date_created', 'questions']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
        quiz = Quiz.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for question in questions_data:
            Question.objects.create(quiz=quiz, **question)

        return quiz
```

When I try to post some data assigned using a JSON file like this one:

```
{
    "name": "quiz",
    "description": "quiz quiz quiz",
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "What is the weather today?",
            "multiple": false,
            "variants": [
                {
                    "variant": "cloudy"
                },
                {
                    "variant": "cold"
                }
            ],
            "answer": "cloudy"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the weather today?",
            "multiple": false,
            "variants": [
                {
                    "variant": "cloudy"
                },
                {
                    "variant": "cold"
                }
            ],
            "answer": "cloudy"
        }
    ] }
```

I get the error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: api_quiz.questions_id`

I am new to this framework, what can I do to post data?

Comment: Your model design is saying a quiz can only have one question, but your request data says a quiz can have more than one question. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add Foreign Key of `Quiz` in `Question` Model, as one quiz can have many questions. Similarly you have to add Foreign Key of `Question` in `Variant` Model, as one question can have many variants. You also need to add related name, that will be helpful in writing nested serailizer. Furthermore, you have to tweak serializers as below:

**models.py**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    multiple = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')

class Variant(models.Model):
    variant = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='variants')
```

**serializer.py**

```
class VariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Variant
        fields = ['id', 'variant']


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    variants = VariantSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id', 'question', 'multiple', 'variants', 'answer']


class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'date_created', 'questions']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        questions_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
        quiz = Quiz.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for question in questions_data:
            variants_data = question.pop('variants')
            question_instance = Question.objects.create(quiz=quiz, **question)
            for variant in variants_data:
                Variant.objects.create(question=question_instance, **variant)

        return quiz
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your models, because a `Quiz` can have only one `Question`

```py
class Variant(models.Model):
    variant = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    multiple = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    variants = models.ForeignKey(Variant, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="questions") 


class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
```

I just added :

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="questions")
```

and removed

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So now you can use :

```py
quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=1)
quiz.questions  # Will return all Question
```

This is explained in django documentations : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Nota bene :
A best practice is never use Model Class when declaring a `ForeignKey` use a string based on `app.ModelName` exemple is your app is call `quizz_exemple` use

`variants = models.ForeignKey("quizz_exemple.Variant", db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`